# ¿En Python, para qué sirve %s y %2i?

Tags: python

¿Para qué sirve `%s` y `%2i`?
Ejemplo:

```py
print("La letra '%s' aparece %2i veces en la frase '%s'."%(letra, contador, frase))
```

Comment: Te recomiendo consultar la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) para aclarar este tipo de dudas.

Comment: sirve para especificar como será formateado el valor que reciba

Comment: es para el formateo del texto, donde `%s` es para decir que se hara un formateo a `string` y `%2i` indica que se hara un formateo a `entero` y se usaran 2 espacios es decir: ' 2' si se pasa 2 se colocaran 1 espacio y el otro lo ocupara el numero si se pasan 10 esta regla se cancela ya que tienes los 2 espacios utilizados, es para indicar cuantos espacios se agregaran en caso de que el numero no llege a dicha longitud.. terminos simples se rellena con espacios si no cumple la longitud deseada!

Comment: @Bryro si te sientes cómodo, ponlo como respuesta (suena a una respuesta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas son instrucciones del lenguaje c que usa python.

El uso de '%s' formatea la cadena por la que está en la tupla, despues del símbolo %, puede ser un arreglo o una variable también.

Es una de las formas, también puedes usar '{}'.format, hace lo mismo, revisa esta documentación:

https://pyformat.info/

El uso de '%i' escanea decimales por defecto.

Revisa python org: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting